# Can I fix version numbers in Flyway without having migrations rerun?

Tags: java, mysql, database, migration, flyway

We've had several migrations set up that were not versioned correctly. The filenames put the version in the description so the db was always at version 0. We want to rename them, but this will cause all of the scripts to rerun.

Currently, our files are named like `V__001_The_First_Migration.sql`.

We want to rename them to `V001__The_First_Migration.sql` without rerunning the migration.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Just fix it for future migrations, otherwise you'll have to manually intervene on any existing databases.

Comment: How many migration scripts have wrong naming issues? Too many? If these are few, I can suggest one solution which might need to fire update queries.

Comment: @MehulGayate, unfortunately, it's well over 100. Some of the scripts have safeguards like `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`, but the effort to put all of those in place would be expensive.

Comment: How did you manage to do this if the version of each script was effectively 0?

Answer (score 2):

I think in FlyWay configuration, there is one property which will help:

```
flyway.baselineVersion=1.0
```

Rename all the files or the files you want to rename and set the "baselineVersion" to the last run or latest script.

Here is more: 
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/baseline

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/baseline

Let me know if you need more help or example.